# Need to remove comma from the end of the array in shell output

Tags: json, bash, shell

(I have created bash script which will extract server information from multiple Linux server by doing SSH. Able to get the json output for all the servers ( from server variable) but need to remove comma at the end of the array for the last server.

I have created variables and provide below print command

```
printf '{"hostname":"%s","UPTIME":"%s","memtotal":"%s","memUsed":"%s","swaptotal":"%s","swapUsed":"%s","cpuUtilization":"%s","disksJson":"%s"},\n' "$HOST" "$UPTIME" "$memTotal" "$memUsed" "$swapTotal" "$swapUsed" "$cpuUtilization" "$disksJson"

(#!/bin/bash
serverlist='/home/user/test/server_list.txt'
servers=`cat $serverlist`
for server in $servers;
do
set -e
# General OS props
HOST=$server
UPTIME=$(ssh user@${server} uptime | awk '{print $3" "$4}'| sed 's/\(.*\),/\1/')

printf '{"hostname":"%s","UPTIME":"%s","memtotal":"%s","memUsed":"%s","swaptotal":"%s","swapUsed":"%s","cpuUtilization":"%s","disksJson":"%s"},\n' "$HOST" "$UPTIME" "$memTotal" "$memUsed" "$swapTotal" "$swapUsed" "$cpuUtilization" "$disksJson"
```

I am getting following json output . I need to keep comma after every server output however do not need comma at the end of the last server output

```
{"hostname":"XXXXXXXX","UPTIME":"24 days","memtotal":"8052704","memUsed":"64.16%","swaptotal":"4190200","swapUsed":"0.00%","cpuUtilization":"0.00%","disksJson":"{"total":"493G", "used":"2%", "mountPoint":"/VEM"},
{"total":"80G", "used":"16%", "mountPoint":"/app_2"},
{"total":"829M", "used":"11%", "mountPoint":"/home"},
{"total":"1.9G", "used":"1%", "mountPoint":"/tmp"}"},

{"hostname":"XXXXXXXX","UPTIME":"11 days","memtotal":"8052704","memUsed":"40.58%","swaptotal":"4190200","swapUsed":"0.00%","cpuUtilization":"0.00%","disksJson":"{"total":"493G", "used":"2%", "mountPoint":"/VEM"},
{"total":"80G", "used":"16%", "mountPoint":"/app_2"},
{"total":"829M", "used":"11%", "mountPoint":"/home"},
{"total":"1.9G", "used":"1%", "mountPoint":"/tmp"}"}, ------- this comma needs to be removed))
```

Comment: Use the `jq` utility to create JSON instead of constructing it by hand. It will ensure that it's formatted correctly. You're also missing the `[]` around the entire array.

Comment: Are you really getting `"/tmp"}"`? Shouldn't that be `"/tmp"`?

Comment: *arg* question was closed before I could submit answer; instead of removing trailing comma, consider modifying the `printf` format string to print `,\n` at the beginning of lines 2-n, eg: `prefix='';for x in server1 server2 server3 server4; do [ "${prefix}" != '' ] && printf "%s\n" "${prefix}";  printf "%s" "${x}"; prefix=',';  done`; resulting output is: `server1,\nserver2,\nserver3,\nserver4`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

After end of `for` loop, add this:

`done | sed '$ s/},/}/'`